# How can I compare two similar strings with a wildcard in bash?

Tags: bash, string-comparison

How can I best compare two similar strings in bash?

I want to compare `1.1.1.1:1000` to `1.1.1.1` and find it to be a match.

```
1.1.1.1:1000 1.1.1.1 MATCH
1.1.1.2:1000 1.1.1.1 NO MATCH
```

Here's a simple script illustrating the challenge:

```
#!/bin/sh

IPONE="1.1.1.1:1000"
IPTWO="1.1.1.1"

if  [[ "$IPONE" == "$IPTWO*" ]] ; then
    echo "$IPONE $IPTWO Match"
else
    echo "$IPONE $IPTWO ERROR"
fi
```

Comment: please accept one of the answers below assuming that one of them resolves your issue.  It doesn't matter which one.  Just whichever one ___best___ answers and resolves your issue.

Comment: Always. But remember there is a minimum time limit that a question must stay open.  You all are too fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compare, for an exact match, the part *before* the colon.  In that case:

```
if  [[ "${IPONE%%:*}" == "${IPTWO%%:*}" ]] ; then
    echo "$IPONE $IPTWO Match"
else
    echo "$IPONE $IPTWO ERROR"
fi
```

Comment: +1 for using substring parameter expansion, and for using it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use glob-syntax, then you need to use `=~` instead of `==` in your `[[ ... ]]`, and you can't have the second parameter quoted.  So it should like this:

```
if [[ "$IPONE" =~ $IPTWO* ]]; then
```

If you **need** to have the second parameter quoted, just do this:

```
if [[ "$IPONE" =~ "$IPTWO"* ]]; then
```

If you need to find a match that matches a string up to the last of a delimiter, in this case `.`, then try this:

```
if [[ "$IPONE" =~ ([0-9]|\.){3}[0-1]* ]]; then
```

Comment: Thanks. That get's me nearly there. The only problem is `1.1.1.2` still returns a match.

Answer (score 1):

I think  [POSIX substring parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), may be have trick

```
#!/bin/bash

IPONE="1.1.1.1:1000"
IPTWO="1.1.1.1"

if test "${IPONE#*$IPTWO}" != "$IPONE"
then
     echo "$IPONE $IPTWO Match"
else
     echo "$IPONE $IPTWO ERROR"
fi
```

OR

```
IPONE="1.1.1.1:1000"
IPTWO="1.1.1.1"

if [[ "${IPONE}" == *$IPTWO* ]]
then
     echo "$IPONE $IPTWO Match"
else
     echo "$IPONE $IPTWO ERROR"
fi
```

Comment: don't use `test`.  Use `[[ ... ]]` when working in bash.  `test` has [problems](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).  Only use `test` when you ___CAN't___ use `[[ ... ]]`